# Reactjs - state updating - Ajax - Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios

Im trying to update my states after a form submit , without refreshing the page.
part of my ReactJs code :

```
export default class DashboardRA extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      json:JSON.parse(props.data),//data received from a laravel controller used to implement the page.
      pdf: '',
    ...
    ...


    async onSubmitButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("pdf", this.state.pdf);
    ...
    const response = await axios.post("/uploadFile", formData, {
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // console.log(response.data); //data from the DB
      this.setState({
        json:JSON.parse(response.data)
      });
    })
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});    
    })
}
```

but it shows the following error : **Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code to

```
.then((response) => {
  // console.log(response.data); //data from the DB
  this.setState({
    json:JSON.parse(response.data)
  });
})
```

You're gwtting the error because when you refer to `this` in `function` you refer to whatever context this function is called in (some Promise internals). By using arrow syntax you're automatically binding it to the context it's declared in (component in your case)

Comment: thank you sooo much , sooo the key is to binding it using the arrow , thanks alot man

Answer (score 1):

It will be because your trying to acces to a method which is no defined in your response function. You have to assign this to variable before running axios. please check this out

```
export default class DashboardRA extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      json:JSON.parse(props.data),//data received from a laravel controller used to implement the page.
      pdf: '',
    ...
    ...


    async onSubmitButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("pdf", this.state.pdf);
    ...


    const my_this = this;


    const response = await axios.post("/uploadFile", formData, {
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      // console.log(response.data); //data from the DB
      my_this.setState({
        json:JSON.parse(response.data)
      });
    })
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
        my_this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});    
    })
}
```

Comment: niiiiice , this is my first time ever i see a binding like this `const my_this = this;` , thank you brother